# What is the meaning of posting a position-opening announcement multiple times at a research-focused institution?

Tags: job-search, faculty-application, academic-life

There was a position-opening announcement posted in a department's homepage of a research-focused institution in the US on February 14, 2015. I firmly believe my experiences and track record make me an excellent fit for this opening. Therefore, I applied for this position on-time. It was mentioned in the opening description that  application material must be received by April 14, 2015 to receive guaranteed consideration, though the search will remain open until the position is filled. However, the strange thing which I noticed that the same opening was posted again in their homepage with new a submission deadline (i.e. June 14, 2015). I then reapplied for this opening. Two months later from this new date, I contacted the Chair of the search committee and asked the status of my application. However, I did not get any response from him.  Just today I got notified from job search engine (verified also in their homepage) that the same opening has provided a new application-submission deadline which has been set to November 1, 2015. I am curious to know what this means. Does it mean that they have not found any suitable candidate for this opening or something else?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what kind of position it is, but are you sure it's not additional instances of the position being offered?

That said, it sounds as if they're not getting the applicant pool or number of applicants that they want.  In my experience, hiring committees want three or four good candidates, even if one stands out from the rest.

Maybe they have found that your qualifications don't meet the requirements as well as you think they do?  Your not getting an email back from the search committee chair is probably significant -- or maybe your email got lost in the internets.

Comment: faculty positions at the rank of tenure-track. Initially they asked for tenure-track assistant/associate/professor levels. But today I noticed that they modified this to assistant professor.

Comment: If faculty positions, it seems pretty clear that they're not getting the applicants they want.  It would be unconscionable for them to keep reopening the position if they had a good candidate, who now has been kept waiting for almost a year.

Comment: Agreed. The scenario seems symptomatic of multiple failed searches.

Comment: Understood! Well, then should I reapply for this position with my updated CV (although not much changes in my CV except adding 1/2 publications)? Or should I try to reach out to the Chair of the search committee to make sure that my qualifications really don't meet the requirements ?

Comment: If nothing much has changed, I wouldn't submit your CV again.  And it would be pretty unusual for a chair to give feedback on your application or listen to you dispute that you are in fact qualified and the committee just isn't seeing it.  Sadly, it sounds as if you need to move on to applying for the next position.

Comment: I appreciate that you don't want to seem pushy.  However, there is nothing wrong with phoning to make sure your application has been received.  During that phone conversation, you can ask a couple of additional questions.  One question to avoid asking in any shape or form: "Do I meet the requirements for the position?"  You may, however, ask: "When the position gets re-announced, should I re-submit my application in order to be considered?"

Comment: I totally agree with aparente001 on the fact that I should not be pushy. However, I am not confident of making call to the Chair of the search committee regarding my application. One thing I could tell that the university did acknowledge that my application was received by them and asked me to fill out  Affirmative Action Form 2 -- Employee Information Request as well as the Voluntary Self-Identification of Disability form.

Comment: @ArafinArif - Could you edit your question to include that information?  Also, could you clarify whether that was after your first or your second submission?  ---  At any rate, perhaps you would be more comfortable speaking with an administrative assistant on the phone.  Or you could try emailing one more time.  Your question: Do I need to re-submit my application for it to be considered in this third round?  Or, rephrased: Will my previous application be automatically considered in this third round, or do I need to re-apply?